# Best practices for forking an Android application/project

Tags: android, fork

An Android application that I am interested in ([OpenSudoku)](http://code.google.com/p/opensudoku-android/) has become unmaintained by the original author, who last updated the application just under a year ago, in addition they have rejects offers of help from others to contribute directly to the hosted SVN repository.

I am interested enough in the project to seriously consider forking it (I am already familar with many arguments for and against forking in general), but I do have a couple of questions related to best practice with forking Android applications, specifically:

1. I understand that I will have to change the package name/namespace, is there an easy method I can use to do this (without breaking the Eclipse project files and associated references)?
2. Is there a way to help users that may want to migrate to the new application, recover settings/data from the original application?  (My understanding is that the permissions model that Android enforces would make this impossible)?
3. Are there any other issues that I should be aware of that comes with forking an Android application that I would need to plan for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. AndroidManifest.xml, various build system files, layouts that use your own views, each Java source file, and the directory tree.  That's what you have to change.  I use `vim -p glob glob glob` for changes like this, and `mv`, which is easy enough.
2. Not unless the old application cooperates, which it likely doesn't.  Perhaps your fork could detect an OpenSudoku install and prompt the user to install, off-market, an 'update' for it that just repackages its preferences for your consumption. I don't know if that works, updating a Market app with a non-market APK. Although, you said "settings/data".  If 'data' includes e.g. sets of puzzles on the sdcard, yes, you can load that kind of data without any trouble -- FAT32 offers no security.

Comment: Thanks!  Managed to get all the references that were required, and thanks for confirming on number 2.